# CSS Stylesheet not showing effects

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am using `Asp.Net/C#`.Currently I am working on the Login page,My `login page` is not dependent on the `Master Page` , and therefore the Link to `Stylesheet` I have set in the head section

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Login.css" type="text/css"/>
```

The problem is that the styles are not having any efeect on my controls on the login page.Here is my css file

```
body
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:75%; 
}
#loginbox
{
     position:fixed;
    background-color:#9cc3f7;
    border:2px solid #ddd;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    top:50%;
   margin-left: -130px;
   margin-top: -100px;
    left:50%;
}
```

Here is the login page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomeLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="CwizBankApp.HomeLogin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">

    <title>Comwizard Systems | Login</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Login.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="loginbox">
    <span>UserName:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br /> 
    <span style="margin-left:6px;">Password:</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />  
    <asp:Button ID="cmdLogin"  runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="cmdLogin_Click" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me with this.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Finally The issue has been solved
Adding this in the web.config solved it

```
<location path="~/Styles">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: 1. check whether the css file is load because href="Styles/Login.css" indicates a relative path to the file. 2. Use a debug tool to check your dom whether there's a loginbox div on the page

Comment: Which browser ? I tried to create a sample out of your code and it works for me. What problems do you run-in, like color not displayed, position not correct, etc.... Please specify in details.

Comment: @AYK....agree with you...code works for me also, may be the issue is due to the problem that CHRIS LEE mention...

Comment: @AYK I tried it in Chrome,Safari,Firefox it is the same,Not a single style is applied.If I use inline styles it works well.

Comment: @freebird....clear your browser cache and run your website again..

Comment: @ChrisLee , could you please explain me what is relative path, how should I refer to the stylesheet then , I forgot to mention that the styles are displayed properly sometimes but when I reload it or come back to page later , the styles disappear

Comment: @freebird, http://brugbart.com/Articles/paths is an explanation of them. Looks like something is wrong with your css file import. Do you mean by getting style problem after reloading the same page or a different page of your site? If it is the same page, then there must be some dynamic content of you page which affects the import of css.

Comment: @@freebird...will you please tell me which version of Chrome, Safari, Firefox you are using????

Comment: @ChrisLee , I think the issue is , I am using forms authentication and when I removed any authentication and set it to windows , it worked.So what could be the issue.Forms authentication is problematic

Comment: @freebird, that may be an access control problem. You better check your loading of .css file when using form auth(You can use firebug for FF, or Chrome's developer tool, or fiddler/httpwatch for IE). See if when browser loading the css the server returns 401. The file s are supposed to be accessible by application pool's identity when using form authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
   <location path="~/stylesheets">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
   </location>
```

please update the path with your Style sheet path....Refer to this article

http://forums.asp.net/t/1678658.aspx/1

Comment: my issue seems to be forms authentication , when i change it to windows authentication it works properly , any workaround you might be able to offer.Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot it helped , my last question to you is when using .js files i will have to repeat it again right and can I create a seperate web.config file and place it in appropriate folders.Thanks for your help

Comment: I asked that if I use .js file , I will have to set permissions for it as well right??

Comment: yes you should have to .. OR .. you can put .js or CSS file in the folder that is not readonly or that donot have any permissions apply on it...

Answer (score 0):

Quick question, could you please check whether the css file is actually resolved?

if you are using chorme, you can use the developer tools and use the network section to see all the requests that go through.

If you are using firefox, use firebug for the same.

Thanks

Comment: I used that in chrome , it the request to Login.css says "recieving".

Answer (score 0):

View the source code (usually by pressing ***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>*** if using chrome/firefox) and find where it says `href="Styles/Login.css"`, you should be able to click that as a link to your stylesheet. You should make sure you're actually linking to it correctly first, does it load properly?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/Login.css")"
```

instead of

```
href="Styles/Login.css"
```

If you are using Visual Studio, intellisense (auto completion) will support you to find the exact location. Just press Ctrl+Space after opening the bracket of Url.Content() method.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your sample and there were no problem at all. The Control "loginbox" do getting css style. please check whether your css file is in the right place.

```
href="Styles/Login.css"
```

Comment: it is in the right folder Styles , but dont know what could be causing the problem

Comment: set background color for the page and verify whether you are getting changes.